# PHP display with readfile 2 seperate files in browser

Tags: php, pdf, browser

Is it possible to display via PHP 2 pdf files in the browser? I want that the second file gets attached to the first file. With one file i did it with:

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filea.pdf"');
readfile(*path*);
```

I tried to attache the 2. file only with readfile but it didn´t worked. Is there a simple way to display the 2 files?

Comment: You might want to zip them into one and download that zip on the user's machine.

Comment: Otherwise, add all pages of 2nd into the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try PDFtk Server. After you install it, you can execute it like this from your PHP script:

```php
exec('pdftk filea.pdf fileb.pdf cat output filec.pdf');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filec.pdf"');
readfile('filec.pdf');
```